# Get values in xarray

Tags: python-3.8, python-xarray

I am new using xarray and I'd like to know how get the values of a class defined as:

```
>>> type(time)
<class 'xarray.core.dataarray.DataArray'>
```

The class has these structure:

```
>>> time
<xarray.DataArray 'time' (time: 65)>
array(['2010-01-01T00:00:00.000000000', '2010-01-01T03:00:00.000000000',
       '2010-01-01T06:00:00.000000000', '2010-01-01T09:00:00.000000000',
       '2010-01-01T12:00:00.000000000', '2010-01-01T15:00:00.000000000',
       '2010-01-01T18:00:00.000000000', '2010-01-01T21:00:00.000000000',
       '2010-01-02T00:00:00.000000000', '2010-01-02T03:00:00.000000000',
       '2010-01-02T06:00:00.000000000', '2010-01-02T09:00:00.000000000',
       '2010-01-02T12:00:00.000000000', '2010-01-02T15:00:00.000000000',
       '2010-01-02T18:00:00.000000000', '2010-01-02T21:00:00.000000000',
       '2010-01-03T00:00:00.000000000', '2010-01-03T03:00:00.000000000',
       '2010-01-03T06:00:00.000000000', '2010-01-03T09:00:00.000000000',
       '2010-01-03T12:00:00.000000000', '2010-01-03T15:00:00.000000000',
       '2010-01-03T18:00:00.000000000', '2010-01-03T21:00:00.000000000',
       '2010-01-04T00:00:00.000000000', '2010-01-04T03:00:00.000000000',
       '2010-01-04T06:00:00.000000000', '2010-01-04T09:00:00.000000000',
       '2010-01-04T12:00:00.000000000', '2010-01-04T15:00:00.000000000',
       '2010-01-04T18:00:00.000000000', '2010-01-04T21:00:00.000000000',
       '2010-01-05T00:00:00.000000000', '2010-01-05T03:00:00.000000000',
       '2010-01-05T06:00:00.000000000', '2010-01-05T09:00:00.000000000',
       '2010-01-05T12:00:00.000000000', '2010-01-05T15:00:00.000000000',
       '2010-01-05T18:00:00.000000000', '2010-01-05T21:00:00.000000000',
       '2010-01-06T00:00:00.000000000', '2010-01-06T03:00:00.000000000',
       '2010-01-06T06:00:00.000000000', '2010-01-06T09:00:00.000000000',
       '2010-01-06T12:00:00.000000000', '2010-01-06T15:00:00.000000000',
       '2010-01-06T18:00:00.000000000', '2010-01-06T21:00:00.000000000',
       '2010-01-07T00:00:00.000000000', '2010-01-07T03:00:00.000000000',
       '2010-01-07T06:00:00.000000000', '2010-01-07T09:00:00.000000000',
       '2010-01-07T12:00:00.000000000', '2010-01-07T15:00:00.000000000',
       '2010-01-07T18:00:00.000000000', '2010-01-07T21:00:00.000000000',
       '2010-01-08T00:00:00.000000000', '2010-01-08T03:00:00.000000000',
       '2010-01-08T06:00:00.000000000', '2010-01-08T09:00:00.000000000',
       '2010-01-08T12:00:00.000000000', '2010-01-08T15:00:00.000000000',
       '2010-01-08T18:00:00.000000000', '2010-01-08T21:00:00.000000000',
       '2010-01-09T00:00:00.000000000'], dtype='datetime64[ns]')
Coordinates:
  * time     (time) datetime64[ns] 2010-01-01 2010-01-01T03:00:00 ... 2010-01-09
Attributes:
    long_name:  time
    bounds:     time_bnds
```

And I would vibe interested to use the values between '', such as:

```
'2010-01-01T00:00:00.000000000'
'2010-01-01T03:00:00.000000000'
....
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A xr.dataarray stores the values in numpy arrays. Here's how you can access the values and optionally convert them to a python list as well (However converting to a list isn't recommended).

```
time_array = time.values
time_list = list(time_array)
```